# Typo3 behind Proxy

Tags: proxy, typo3

I'm trying to get a Typo3 (6.2) instance running behind a (forwarding) proxy (squid). I have set

```
'HTTP' => array(
            'adapter' => 'curl',
            'proxy_host' => 'my.local.proxy.ip',
            'proxy_port' => '8080',
)
```

as well as

```
'SYS' => array(
            'curlProxyServer' => 'http://my.local.proxy.ip:8080',
            'curlUse' => '1'
    )
```

The proxy doesn't ask for credentials.

When I try to update the extension list, I get the error message

> Update Extension List
>   Could not access remote resource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.

If I try Get preconfigured distribution, it says

> 1342635425
>   Could not access remote resource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.

According to the proxy log, the server doesn't even try to connect to the proxy.

I can easily download the file using wget on the command line.

Ok, I've investigated he issue a bit more and from what I can tell, the Typo3 doesn't even **try** to connect **anywhere**.

I used tcpdump and wireshark to analyze the network traffic. The site claims to have tried sending a http-Request to repositories.typo3.org so I'd expect to find either a proxy connection attempt or a DNS query followed by an attempt to connect to that IP. (Of course, the latter is known not to work.) However, none of this happens.

I've tried some slight changes in the variable curlProxyServer. The documentation clearly states

> > String: Proxyserver as http://proxy:port/. Deprecated since 4.6 - will be removed in TYPO3 CMS 7. See below for http options.

So I tried adding the trailing "/" and removing the "http://" - no change. I'm confident there's no problem whatsoever regarding the proxy as the proxy isn't even contacted and has been working perfectly fine for everything else for years.

Comment: You would need to debug this to find out more.

Comment: ...but the configuration itself seems to be ok, so it should - theoretically - work? I admit that I would have preferred some stupid mistake on my side. ;-)

Comment: Well, I do not use proxies to connect to the web ;)

Comment: Thats good for you and neither do I, but as far as this particular Typo3 instance is concerned, this is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

The error message comes from `\TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Utility\Repository\Helper::fetchFile()`. This one uses `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getUrl()` to get the actual file content.
According to your setting, it should use the first part of the function, because `curlUse` is set and the URL starts with `http` or `https`.

So what you would need to do now is to throw some debug lines in the code and check at what point the request goes wrong.

Look at the source code, three possibilities come to mind:

1. The curl proxy parameters does not support a scheme, thus it should be `'curlProxyServer' => 'my.local.proxy.ip:8080',`.
2. Some redirect does not work.
3. Your proxy has problems with `https`, because the `TYPO3 TER` should be queried over `https`.

Comment: +1 for being the first who gave it a deeper thought. My priorities were shifted a bit, but as soon as I get back to this I will try it and post an update.